# Don't understand how this is calling the fadeIn method in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a line from a plugin that i'm using that im trying to understand:

```
$self.hide().attr("src", $self.data(settings.data_attribute))[settings.effect](settings.effect_speed);
```

self is a jquery object, which in this code is an img dom element, it hides it, then sets the src attribute of this img object to the html5 data-attribute. but now its accessing a property in the jquery object returned by .attr(, which is "fadeIn" in this. but i dont understand, do jquery objects have that built in where an effect property function is built into the jquery object? im confused how this is translates to calling .fadeIn( 900 ). i can't find this documented anywhere on the jquery website. if anyone can shed some light on this, thank you.

sorry, here is the full code, it is from mika tuupola's lazy loading jquery plugin:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
var $window = $jq191(window);

$jq191.fn.lazyload = function(options) {
    var elements = this;
    var $container;
    var settings = {
        threshold       : 0,
        failure_limit   : 0,
        event           : "scroll",
        effect          : "show",
        container       : window,
        data_attribute  : "original",
        skip_invisible  : true,
        appear          : null,
        load            : null
    };

    function update() {
        var counter = 0;

        elements.each(function() {
            var $this = $jq191(this);
            if (settings.skip_invisible && !$this.is(":visible")) {
                return;
            }
            if ($jq191.abovethetop(this, settings) ||
                $jq191.leftofbegin(this, settings)) {
                    /* Nothing. */
            } else if (!$jq191.belowthefold(this, settings) &&
                !$jq191.rightoffold(this, settings)) {
                    $this.trigger("appear");
                    /* if we found an image we'll load, reset the counter */
                    counter = 0;
            } else {
                if (++counter > settings.failure_limit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    if(options) {
        /* Maintain BC for a couple of versions. */
        if (undefined !== options.failurelimit) {
            options.failure_limit = options.failurelimit; 
            delete options.failurelimit;
        }
        if (undefined !== options.effectspeed) {
            options.effect_speed = options.effectspeed; 
            delete options.effectspeed;
        }

        $jq191.extend(settings, options);
    }

    /* Cache container as jQuery as object. */
    $container = (settings.container === undefined ||
                  settings.container === window) ? $window : $jq191(settings.container);

    /* Fire one scroll event per scroll. Not one scroll event per image. */
    if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
        $container.bind(settings.event, function(event) {
            return update();
        });
    }

    this.each(function() {
        var self = this;
        var $self = $jq191(self);

        self.loaded = false;

        /* When appear is triggered load original image. */
        $self.one("appear", function() {
            if (!this.loaded) {
                if (settings.appear) {
                    var elements_left = elements.length;
                    settings.appear.call(self, elements_left, settings);
                }
                $jq191("<img />")
                    .bind("load", function() {
                        $self
                            .hide()
                            .attr("src", $self.data(settings.data_attribute))
                            [settings.effect](settings.effect_speed);
                        self.loaded = true;

                        /* Remove image from array so it is not looped next time. */
                        var temp = $jq191.grep(elements, function(element) {
                            return !element.loaded;
                        });
                        elements = $jq191(temp);

                        if (settings.load) {
                            var elements_left = elements.length;
                            settings.load.call(self, elements_left, settings);
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("src", $self.data(settings.data_attribute));
            }
        });

        /* When wanted event is triggered load original image */
        /* by triggering appear.                              */
        if (0 !== settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
            $self.bind(settings.event, function(event) {
                if (!self.loaded) {
                    $self.trigger("appear");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    /* Check if something appears when window is resized. */
    $window.bind("resize", function(event) {
        update();
    });

    /* With IOS5 force loading images when navigating with back button. */
    /* Non optimal workaround. */
    if ((/iphone|ipod|ipad.*os 5/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
        $window.bind("pageshow", function(event) {
            if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
                elements.each(function() {
                    $jq191(this).trigger("appear");
                });
            }
        });
    }

    /* Force initial check if images should appear. */
    $jq191(window).load(function() {
        update();
    });

    return this;
};

/* Convenience methods in jQuery namespace.           */
/* Use as  $jq191.belowthefold(element, {threshold : 100, container : window}) */

$jq191.belowthefold = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.height() + $window.scrollTop();
    } else {
        fold = $jq191(settings.container).offset().top + $jq191(settings.container).height();
    }

    return fold <= $jq191(element).offset().top - settings.threshold;
};

$jq191.rightoffold = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.width() + $window.scrollLeft();
    } else {
        fold = $jq191(settings.container).offset().left + $jq191(settings.container).width();
    }

    return fold <= $jq191(element).offset().left - settings.threshold;
};

$jq191.abovethetop = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.scrollTop();
    } else {
        fold = $jq191(settings.container).offset().top;
    }

    return fold >= $jq191(element).offset().top + settings.threshold  + $jq191(element).height();
};

$jq191.leftofbegin = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.scrollLeft();
    } else {
        fold = $jq191(settings.container).offset().left;
    }

    return fold >= $jq191(element).offset().left + settings.threshold + $jq191(element).width();
};

$jq191.inviewport = function(element, settings) {
     return !$jq191.rightoffold(element, settings) && !$jq191.leftofbegin(element, settings) &&
            !$jq191.belowthefold(element, settings) && !$jq191.abovethetop(element, settings);
 };

/* Custom selectors for your convenience.   */
/* Use as $jq191("img:below-the-fold").something() or */
/* $jq191("img").filter(":below-the-fold").something() which is faster */

$jq191.extend($jq191.expr[':'], {
    "below-the-fold" : function(a) { return $jq191.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "above-the-top"  : function(a) { return !$jq191.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "right-of-screen": function(a) { return $jq191.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "left-of-screen" : function(a) { return !$jq191.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "in-viewport"    : function(a) { return $jq191.inviewport(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    /* Maintain BC for couple of versions. */
    "above-the-fold" : function(a) { return !$jq191.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "right-of-fold"  : function(a) { return $jq191.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "left-of-fold"   : function(a) { return !$jq191.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); }
});
```

})($jq191, window, document);

Comment: Is the full code available anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember, jQuery is just an object. That means all of the methods you can call with `.` notation, you can call with `[]` notation. Ergo, the two lines are functionally identical:

```
$("#foo").fadeIn(2000);
$("#foo")['fadeIn'](2000);
```

The other items, `settings.effect` and `settings.effect_speed` are likely being fed into the plugin via an object literal that carries options for the plugin.

```
var settings = {
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    effect_speed: 2000
}
```

Comment: @Masu My pleasure. I've never seen anybody tampering with jQuery in that fashion, so thank you for something new ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is why this works.

First, jQuery's `.hide()` method and its `.attr(name,value)` method each return `this` in the usual fashion of such jQuery methods, to allow chaining. But that also means we can *remove* those calls without affecting the question:

```
$self[settings.effect](settings.effect_speed);
```

Now it's simpler. `settings.effect` is the string `"fadeIn"`, right?

Then the code is the same as:

```
$self["fadeIn"](settings.effect_speed);
```

In JavaScript, `object["methodName"]` means exactly the same thing as `object.methodName`. So the code is really the same as:

```
$self.fadeIn(settings.effect_speed);
```

and that's why it calls the `fadeIn` method.